# angularjs ng-options with custom filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angular-filters

Sorry to ask this question again but no answer or workaround has been identified.

This is a follow-up of this question : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414417/angularjs-select-with-filter-leaves-first-line-empty-but-not-when-filter-is-appl)

I have a plunker which describes the issue (basically putting a tree structure in a dropdown list) :

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UDMiql?p=preview)

As illustrated the first select does not select the value and gets back to an empty line - which is also a mystery.

I have not been able to find any similar cases and I am close to giving up so this is the last chance.

Key code areas are the filter and the initTreeSelect function :

```
$scope.initTreeSelect = function(tree){
   $scope.filteredFields = $filter('flattenTree')(tree);
   return $scope.filteredFields[0];

};


angular.module('myApp.filters', []).filter('flattenTree', function (OrgSvc) {
return function (array) {
  var arrayToReturn = [];        
    arrayToReturn = OrgSvc.flattenTree(array);
    return arrayToReturn;

};})
```

Your help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: could you describe more about what's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Dayan Moreno Leon wrote in his answer is actually correct. And the problem really is that angular keeps losing track of the model data (because by default objects/arrays are identified by reference).

This is thwarted, because your `flattenTree` keeps returning newly created objects:

```
flatTree.push({id:tree[i].id, display:tree[i].display, parentId:tree[i].parentId});
```

For your concrete problem though, I think using `track by` will help, e.g.:

```
<select
  class='form-control' 

  ng-model="treeValue1"
  ng-init="treeValue1 = initTreeSelect(fields)"
  ng-options="element as element.display for element in fields | flattenTree track by element.id"
></select>
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/J8PyypC61uzx8PPNV6Zu?p=preview

Comment: So, I did **[all this hard work](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkryET5MnXFIq0Jg9na3?p=preview)** for nothing ? Grrr...

Comment: @ExpertSystem Sorry! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot to you two! I understand the issue now. Indeed I could have just replaced the flattenTree part with flatTree.push(tree[i]) and that would have kept the binding. I understand Dayan Moreno Leon's answer much better now. Guys you have ended my one-week battle with this. I wish you an awesome day!